# VC++ builds for WAMP PHP upgrade

Tags: php, visual-c++, wamp

Currently i have Php 5.3.13 on WAMP 2.2 and wish to upgrade php to next higher version. Also I've VS 2010 installed on my machine.  While installing wamp 2.2, i installed VC9. Will installing VC11 affect my existing visual studio components?

**Edit - Sorry, i missed it.  I'm doing dot net development and hence i've installed VS2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to install the Visual Studio Suite. All that is required are the correct Visual Studio Version **Runtime Libraries**.

Do a google using "msvc runtime" as the search and you will get links to all the various versions of the **Runtime Libraries**. Its never a bad idea to have a complete set, as they are used by any software compiled with the MS Visual C/C++ compiler. If you are using a 64bit Windows then its also a good idea to download the 32bit and 64bit versions as of course Windows 64bit will also run Windows 32bit code.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. I've my dot net development in my machine (sorry i missed it to state in detail earlier), will installin vc11 run-time library affect the dot net setup.

Comment: No it wont effect the compiler

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, Will proceed and update the outcome